# PHP substring delete

Tags: php, string

How do I remove entire characters from a string starting from a particular string position to another position, and shift the rest to merge with this starting position?

I'm working with HTML contents. So take this for example.

```
</a></h4><p class="pdesc">When a private satellite encounters .... and it is found to ...</p></div></div>.....<p class="pdesc">Before leavingon his .... </p> ...... <p class="pdesc"> .... </p>
```

So now I want to remove all characters in between

```
<p class="pdesc"> - to - </p>.
```

of every occurrence.

I can search for this (strpos) and get the starting and the ending positions, but then manually deleting them and shifting strings from then on will be too tedious.

Is there a built in function or a simple way to do it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the [`substr_replace`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/substr_replace) function:

```
$var = 'ABCDEFGH:/MNRPQR/';

/* Delete 'MNRPQR' from $var. */
echo substr_replace($var, '', $start = 10, $length = -1) . "<br />\n";
```